# disable buttons according to Predicate in JavaFX8

Tags: javafx-8

I'm working on a PDF viewer using JavaFX8 and have "page up" and "page down" button. I want the "page up" button to be disabled if the currently displayed page is the first page.

First, I haved added a isFirstPage `BooleanProperty` instance variable to my controller (which I set to true or false depending on the current page number), this works fine, but it seems overkill to add an instance variable for every state of the application (isFirstPage, isLastPage, isDocumentLoaded etc).

What I want to achieve is to bind the disableProperty to a Predicate (whichs is evaluated every time the selectedPageNo changes), but apparently I'm doing somethign wrong as the code is not working (the buttons is never disabled):

```
nextPageButton.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() ->
                 selectedPageNo.intValue() >= currentDocument.getNumberOfPages()));
```

Here `selectedPageNo` is a `IntegerProperty` and `currentDocument` a `org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three different ways:

**`IntegerProperty` API**

You can just do

```
nextPageButton.disableProperty().bind(
    selectedPageNo.greaterThanOrEqualTo(currentDocument.getNumberOfPages()));
```

If the number of pages might change and is also represented by an `IntegerProperty`, then

```
nextPageButton.disableProperty().bind(
    selectedPageNo.greaterThanOrEqualTo(currentDocument.numberOfPagesProperty()));
```

will observe both properties and update as required.

**Bindings API**

For more general calculations that aren't supported by the methods `IntegerProperty` inherits from [`NumberExpressionBase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/NumberExpressionBase.html), you can use the [`Bindings` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html) almost as you used it. The thing you omitted was to provide the properties that the binding needs to observe:

```
nextPageButton.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> 
    selectedPageNo.intValue() >= currentDocument.getNumberOfPages(),
    selectedPageNo));
```

**Subclass `BooleanBinding`**

An alternative is to subclass `BooleanBinding` directly:

```
nextPageButton.disableProperty().bind(new BooleanBinding() {
    {
        bind(selectedPageNo);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean computeValue() {
        return selectedPageNo.intValue() >= currentDocument.getNumberOfPages();
    }
});
```